# Problem with particle system in blender 2.9

Tags: rendering, particles

[image]

I have water droplets raining down from my shower head and when I look at them in Viewport they start at the shower head, but when I render them it looks like that. Does anyone know what could be the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any kind of material based displacement on your emitter? If so, that could case the object to be rendert at a different position then in the viewport.

Comment: No I don't but I have collision on the shower head. Could it be that I have some settings wrong there that cause the problem? Oh and thank you none the less for the sugestion

Comment: I don't know about any settings on a collision mesh, that could change the appearance in the render but not in the viewport, but im not completely certain, that something like this couldn't exist, sorry.